# How can AP work without having IP address assigned?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ip-address

I have an an ASUS EA-AC87 AP which I cannot re-configure since I cannot find it in the network.

Network structure:

[EA-AC87(AP)] <-UTP-> [RT-AC68U(DHCP, WAN)] <-UTP-> [Fiber Optic Transceiver] <---> [World Wide Web]

It was configured when I bought it and became inaccessible shortly afterward. It doesn't get an IP address assigned, however devices still can access both the LAN and Internet through it. The factory reset button doesn't work either.

Note: This is not support request for mentioned router, just a bit of background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An access point's IP address is only used to access its configuration. The IP address is not involved in the task of handling  wireless clients' traffic. An AP is a [OSI Layer 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer?wprov=sfla1) bridge and only inspects MAC addresses when forwarding frames.

Consider this scenario: An access point is configured with the IP address `192.168.1.2`. The AP is then connected to a wired network that has a DHCP server offering addresses from the IP subnetwork `10.0.0.0/16`.

Clients that associate with the AP will get an IP address from the wired network's DHCP server and will be able to communicate on the 10.0.0.0/16 network without trouble.

However, if one wishes to access the AP's management interface, they must configure a device with a static IP address in the `192.168.1.x`. subnetwork.

In function an access point is an [OSI Layer 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer?wprov=sfla1) bridge. It connects different types of physical networks to each other (bridging), and forwards *frames* between them (a layer 2 operation). Because IP addresses exist on [Layer 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer?wprov=sfla1), an AP doesn't have any awareness of them in terms of performing its regular duties. It works with MAC addresses, not IP addresses, to know whether a frame should be forwarded from one network segment to the other.

---

#### Finding Your AP's IP Address

If you know roughly what IP subnetwork your AP should have an IP address on, such as in the 192.168.1.x subnetwork, configure a device with a static IP address with access to the same network. Then use a IP scanning tool to ping all possible IP address on the subnetwork. I like the [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org) for this. Try connecting to each IP that responds until you find your AP (assuming it's working correctly!)

Comment: Well, after many years in IT, I didn't knew that. Thanks! Btw I updated question with a bit of scheme how my network looks like.

Answer (score 1):

A wireless access point doesn't get its own IP address from the DHCP server. Rather it just passes through the network traffic as a wired switch would do.

To access the configuration of your access point you usually have to connect your PC with a wire to the access point and set up a fixed IP on your PC. The procedure to access the configuration page should be explained in your manual.

Otherwise you should be able to navigate to your AP's configuration page by going to http://findasus.local/ in a browser window. You might have to be connected to your AP via a wire to do this.